# Nginx not working after docker restart policy = always

Tags: django, nginx, docker-compose

My team is using Docker Compose to serve a Django web application. We have one container that serves Django via a Gunicorn web server, and another container that is a reverse http proxy to the first container using Nginx (it also serves static files).

We are trying to implement docker's "always" restart policy. Here is the issue:

Right after a reboot (or after taking docker engine down and bringing it back up), when we visit our web page in the browser we see a "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE localhost didn't send any data" error. A quick "docker-compose ps" shows that both containers are running despite not working as expected. But when we do "docker-compose restart", THEN everything works as expected.

I have been inspecting our setup trying to localize the issue, and all I know is that it is an issue with the Nginx container after it is automatically restarted by docker. I mapped a port on my host machine to our Gunicorn container, and I can access the Gunicorn container and that container works as expected after the auto restart. So by process of elimination, it must be an issue with the Nginx container.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/luisnaranjo733/b14ffb358b207c3f25c8a3b03f49cae7) is our docker-compose.yml file.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/luisnaranjo733/8978330fc39d37a9f31fe94341b647ae) is the Gunicorn Dockerfile.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/luisnaranjo733/fe76bd71d22be3577b9f2473d8b83037) is our Nginx config file.

Does anyone have any insight into what might be the cause of this problem? Or even better, a solution? Looking for ideas. Thanks!

Comment: What's the version of Docker?

Answer (score 1):

I have a Nginx Proxy in front of my services all other services are restarting fine after reboot but `nginx-proxy` does not restart. I am using `docker-compose` file for it. To resolve this issue I have created a `systemd` service file called `nginx-proxy-container.service` in `/etc/systemd/system` like below

```
Description=NGinx Proxy App
After=docker.service
Requires=docker.service

[Service]
TimeoutStartSec=0
Restart=always
ExecStartPre=-/usr/local/bin/docker-compose -f /path/to/docker-compose.yml down
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/docker-compose -f /path/to/docker-compose.yml up -d

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

then I reloaded the deamon config and and start it like below

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start nginx-proxy-container.service
# this start container when OS restarts
sudo systemctl enable nginx-proxy-container.service
```

If you are looking for pure Docker solution please take a look into [docker-systemd](https://github.com/ibuildthecloud/systemd-docker) project

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

A issue on github describes exactly your issue: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/872

> This link says that there was an issue with docker engine 1.4. This is
>   fixed in later versions.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16787857)

Comment: @OmG I rewrote the abstraction and highlighted it. Hope it's more clear now.